# Change date format to string to show just the month and the year

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I'm trying to change the format of my refDate to show just the month and year eg "july 2020", but it's not working , ive tried alot of examples , but its still not working.
This shows the date in this format "2020 07 23", but I want it to be just the month and the year.

```
    function d(t, a, e) {
      var n = t.find("input.refDate").val(),
        r = "";
      r = "subtract" == a ? moment(n, l.format).subtract(e, "days") : moment(n, l.format).add(e, "days"), t.find("input.refDate").val(r.format(l.format)), o(t, r)
    }

    var l = t.extend({
      id: "rescalendar",
      format: ("YYYY MM DD"),
      refDate: moment().format("YYYY MM DD"),
      jumpSize: 15,
      calSize: 30,
      locale: "en",
      disabledDays: [],
      disabledWeekDays: [],
      dataKeyField: "name",
      dataKeyValues: [],
      data: {},
      lang: {
        init_error: "Error when initializing",
        no_data_error: "No data found",
        no_ref_date: "No refDate found",
        today: "Today"
      },
      template_html: function (t, a) {
        return ['<div class="blue-text rescalendar', t.attr("id"), '_wrapper">', '<div class="container"> <div class="rescalendar_controls d-flex justify-content-center">', '<button class="btn p-0 ml-auto move_to_last_month"> <img src="prev-icon.svg" alt=""> </button>', '<!--<button class="btn move_to_yesterday"> <img src="prev-icon.svg" alt=""> </button>-->', '<input style="width:40%;" id="refDate" class="refDate m-0" value=" ' + a.refDate + '" readonly />', '<!--<button class="btn move_to_tomorrow"> <img src="next-icon.svg" alt=""> </button>-->', '<button class="btn p-0 mr-auto move_to_next_month"> <img src="next-icon.svg" alt=""> </button>', "<br>", '<!--<button class="move_to_today"> ' + a.lang.today + " </button>-->", "</div></div>", '<div class="container py-2 text-center"> ', '<span class="rescalendar_day_cells"></span>', "", '<!--<tbody class="rescalendar_data_rows">', "</tbody>-->", "</div>"].join("")
      }
    }, a);
```

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you can delete the parts of your code that are not relevant to your question, to make it easier for us to find the part that is relevant

Comment: So change the lines with that format!  `format: ("YYYY MM DD"),
      refDate: moment().format("YYYY MM DD"),`

Comment: I tried that , but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that. You can wrap it in function and call while constructing object

```js
// Get current time
const now = new Date();

// Set months name array
const monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

// Format result
console.log(`${monthNames[now.getMonth()]} ${now.getFullYear()}`);
```